# Trying to make a canvas "jump"

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a canvas jump. By jumping I mean moving up for a kinda sort time and then going down to the floor again. Something is obviously wrong because nothing happen when I press space. Can't think of what's wrong with my code, any ideas?

```
var spaceKey = false;
var player = {
  side: 20,
  x: 0,
  y: HEIGHT - 20,
  color: "red"

};

context.fillStyle = player.color;
context.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.side, player.side);

setInterval(update, 1000/60);

function update(){
  clearCanvas();

  if (spaceKey){
    jump();
  } 

  draw();
}

function jump(){
  // Moving the player 5 px up 60 times every 10ms.
  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++){
    function jumpUp(){
      player.y -= 5;
    }
    setTimeout(10, jumpUp);

  }
  // Moving the player 5 px down 60 times every 10ms.
  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++){
    function jumpDown(){
      player.y += 5;
    }
    setTimeout(10, jumpDown);
  }

}


function onKeyDown(evt) {
        //Making spaceKey true onclick and calling the jump function.
        if (evt.keyCode == 32) spaceKey = true;

    }

function onKeyUp(evt) {

      if (evt.keyCode == 32) spaceKey = false;

}

window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);

window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, false);
```

(This is not all of my code, and if you want me to add any more code please let me know.)Thanks

I changed my jump function to this:

```
function jump(){
  // Moving the player 5 px up 60 times every 10ms.
  function jumpUp(){
    player.y -= 5;
  }
  function jumpDown(){
    player.y += 5;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++){

    requestAnimationFrame(jumpUp);
  }
  // Moving the player 5 px down 60 times every 10ms.
  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++){

      requestAnimationFrame(jumpDown);
  }
}
```

still not working though.

Comment: This won't be the whole problem, but you have syntax errors in the above: You can't have a function *declaration* directly inside a control-flow structure like `for`, as you do for `jumpUp` and `jumpDown`. JavaScript engines have an (unfortunate) tendency to try to rewrite that for you, but they do it *differently* (and not all engines tolerate it). You can't use `for` loops for what you're trying to do anyway, but if you could, you'd want those to be function *expressions* instead. Also note that the function comes *first*, then the timeout; you have it backward in your `setTimeout` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeouts are not chained nor summed. The browser does not want for the previous Timeout to have run before executing the next. It tries to run a timeout `timeoutArg` ms after the moment it is registered.
All your callbacks will be executed more or less at the same time here: 10 ms after being registered.

This should work:

```js
var player = { y: 0 };

function jump(){
  function jumpUp(){
    player.y -= 5;
    render();
  }
  function jumpDown(){
    player.y += 5;
    render();
  }
  // Moving the player 5px up every 10ms for 600ms (i.e. 5px up 60 times).
  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++){
    setTimeout(jumpUp , i * 10);
  }
  // Same but down.
  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++){
    setTimeout(jumpDown, i * 10 + 600);
  }
}

jump();

// This is just an example.
var repr = document.getElementById("player");
function render(){
  repr.style.top = 150 + player.y / 3 + "px";
}
```

```css
#player {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
```

However, be aware that **using timeouts for animation is bad practice**. One should use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead and base the animation progress on time, not on frames (frame rate is unreliable). Here is an example of the user of requestAnimationFrame.

```js
var player = { y: 0 };

function jumpFunc(progress){
  return 1 - Math.abs(1 - progress * 2);
  // You may want to use a sinusoid instead of a linear function here.
  // It usually looks more realistic. E.g. :
  // return Math.sin(progress * Math.PI);
}

function jump(startTime, initY){
  var duration = 1200;
  var amplitude = 300;
  startTime = startTime || Date.now();
  initY = initY || player.y;
  var progress = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (Date.now() - startTime) / duration));
  player.y = initY - jumpFunc(progress) * amplitude;
  render();
  if(progress < 1){
     requestAnimationFrame(jump.bind(null, startTime, initY));
  }
}

// This is just an example.
var repr = document.getElementById("player");
function render(){
  repr.style.top = 150 + player.y / 3 + "px";
}

jump();
```

```css
#player {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
```

Comment: Why i * 10? When i is like 50 that would take the program half a second. Right? Wouldn't just 10 be better? Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441199/trying-to-make-a-canvas-jump-javascript#comment62385472_37441199) on the question, which applies to the code in the answer as well (since the answer copies the relevant code from the question).

Comment: Oh, I did not even notice the inverted setTimeout. About the remaining though, I am not convinced why the use a for loop would not work here. As far as I know, the danger of in-loop functions is if the functions use the iterated variable (i.e. `i`) which often leads to unexpected results. But it is not the case here (though redefining the functions at each iteration is useless here).

Comment: @Roque: I'm having a hard time understanding what the OP really wants to do, maybe the above will do it. "Moving the playe r5 px up 60 times every 10ms" doesn't fit with what I see above, but maybe the comment is what's wrong. Nice one fixing the `setTimeout` and function declaration issues.

Comment: @UlrikKarlsson Because you do not all all your callbacks to be executed at the same time. Using `i` makes the first executed 10ms after being registered, the second 20ms and so on.

Comment: Hmm, I use the fillRect thing which is inside a larger canvas. The larger canvas has a border and when I press space the entire thing starts moving. It is very, very buggy. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Scrubben/nzmd6pd9/, Thanks for making it work though!!!

Comment: Never mind, I solved it quite easily. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: You're welcome. However, once again, setTimeout and setInterval are a **bad** way to do animations. requestAnimationFrame is here for that. It is more efficient (the browser will be able to make diverse optimisation) and consume less power.